# Bhabha scattering Energy conservation

Tags: quantum-field-theory, elementary-particles

Griffiths Ex. 2.4 in his book "Elementary particles" says:

> "Determine the mass of the virtual photon in each of the lowest-order
>   diagrams for Bhabha scattering (assume the electron and positron are
>   at rest). What is its velocity? (Note that these answers would be
>   impossible for real photons)"

I know that the mass in the Annihilation Diagram is $m=2m_e$ using the Center of Momentum system and the formula $E^2 - p^2c^2 = m^2c^4$. I'm considering as three different steps

($e^-e^+,\gamma,e^-e^+$),

and conservation over each of them (each vertex before and after).

[image: Annihilation]

(Time goes horizontally).

But what about the Scattering diagram

[image: Scattering]

The virtual photon is it part of the "before interaction" or "after interaction"? Is it part of both? that would make $m=0$. If not it would be $m=2m_e$ considering the virtual photon as a middle step.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(2nd diagram) Since the photon is virtual, its exchange is the process that happens *during* interaction, neither before nor after.

Now, energy and 3-momentum is conserved at each vertex. Also keep in mind that there is a total [initial(i) or final(f)] energy-momentum 4-vector conservation delta function in any scattering process: $\delta(\sum p_i^\mu - \sum p_f^\mu)$.

Using these, in the 2nd diagram, for the topmost vertex (with photon energy/momentum flowing into the vertex), energy conservation gives $E_{e^+(in)} + E_\gamma = E_{e^+(out)}$. Since $E_{e^+} = m$ for both, $E_\gamma=0$. Similarly, $\vec{p}_{e^+(in)} + \vec{p}_\gamma = \vec{p}_{e^+(out)}$ gives $\vec{p}_\gamma = 0$, and therefore, photon velocity $=0$. Now, using the energy-momentum dispersion relation for these values of $E_\gamma$ and $\vec{p}_\gamma$, we find that $m_\gamma=0$.

As Griffiths points out, this is not possible for real photons: they can never have zero velocity.